# "get its delivery" or "get it delivery"?

Tags: grammar

Tell me please which one is correct in the following sentence:

> It is the difference between buying a pizza at a grocery store and getting **it**  delivery.
>
> It is the difference between buying a pizza at a grocery store and getting **its**  delivery.

Comment: Are you trying to say *getting it* ***delivered***? You can also *get delivery*, without a pronoun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean getting **it delivered**.

> It is the difference between buying a pizza at a grocery store and
>   getting **it delivered**.

Answer (score 1):

Use it as 
1. It is the difference between buying a pizza at a grocery store and getting it delivered.
Or
2. It is the difference between buying a pizza at a grocery store and waiting for its delivery(at somewhere).

Comment: "Waiting for its delivery" is not idiomatic.

Comment: Okey then we could write it as waiting it to be delivered (at somewhere). ?

Comment: The usual preposition would be _to_, not _at_: *...and waiting for it to be delivered to the office*. That said, one could say: *...and waiting at the office for it to be delivered.*